# Parsing list of items with DCG?

Tags: list, parsing, prolog, dcg

How do you parse string which is list of items f.e.

```
  1,2,3,4
  aa,b,ccc,ddd
```

Currently I do this (and is the comma) :

```
sub(X,Y) --> req(X), [and], req(Y).
sub(X) --> req(X).

req(on(X,Y)) --> [X,is,on,the,Y],!.
req(on(X,Y)) --> [X,is,on,Y],!.
req(on(X,Y)) --> [X,on,Y],!.
req(isa(X,Y)) --> [X,is,a,Y].


?- phrase(sub(T,U),[box,is,on,the,table, and, box,is,a,object], R).
T = on(box, table),
U = isa(box, object),
R = [].
```

but in this case sub() have two different heads sub(X) and sub(X,Y) , which messes the higher level.

---

I did this :

```
sub([X|Y]) --> req(X), [and], sub(Y).
sub([X]) --> req(X).
```

which seems to work ... but returns too many results ..??

```
?- phrase(sub(T),[box,is,on,the,table, and, box,is,a,object, and, apple , is,a,fruit], R).
T = [on(box, table), isa(box, object), isa(apple, fruit)],
R = [] ;
T = [on(box, table), isa(box, object)],
R = [and, apple, is, a, fruit] ;
T = [on(box, table)],
R = [and, box, is, a, object, and, apple, is, a|...].
```

it should stop at the first results ...!!

---

ooo i have to reverse the order, right ?

```
sub([X]) --> req(X).
sub([X|Y]) --> req(X), [and], sub(Y).
```

Answer (score 1):

With your last definition:

```
sub([X]) --> req(X).
sub([X|Y]) --> req(X), [and], sub(Y).
```

The following queries work:

```
?- phrase(sub(Sub), [box,is,on,the,table, and, box,is,a,object]).
Sub = [on(box, table), isa(box, object)] ;
false.

?- phrase(sub(Sub), [box,is,on,the,table, and, box,is,a,object, and, apple,is,a,fruit]).
Sub = [on(box, table), isa(box, object), isa(apple, fruit)] ;
false.
```

Note that I only give two arguments to `phrase`. `phrase` has a form with two arguments, and one with three arguments. As a beginner, you will almost certainly only want to use the two-argument form. The two-argument form parses the entire list you give it and succeeds only if really everything in the list could be parsed. This is almost certainly what you want as a beginner. The three-argument form allows you to parse only the beginning of a list, then get back the suffix that wasn't parsed. You are not advanced enough to need this.

Comment: yep, thanks... i used /3 because it shows me what is left, when i do it wrong